# Cannot redefine property: googletag

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern

```
Uncaught runtime errors:
ERROR

> Cannot redefine property: googletag TypeError: Cannot redefine
> property: googletag
>     at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
>     at <anonymous>:1:196
>     at <anonymous>:1:524
```

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: Our web app has also been receiving this error recently. not able to reproduce locally, something our sentry error handling is picking up.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any Adblocker installed, try to whitelist your website in it and refresh the page. This solved the error for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's Stands. I've put a report in to the author, but not sure if they are going to fix it or not.

If Chromium would fix https://issues.chromium.org/issues/41003071 we might have a chance of being able to ignore extension authors not handling their errors properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please uninstall all extension from chrome browser to resolve google tag error.

This way works for me.